# package expo.modules does not exist

Tags: android, react-native

I have created my react native project using npx react-native init project_name

Then I have build the project and it was building successfully.
Next thing I wanted to add expo-local-authentication package to my project, so I have followed the instrunction given by the official documentation i.e, https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/main/packages/expo-local-authentication
For bare React Native projects, you must ensure that you have installed and configured the expo package before continuing.

So I have installed the expo module in my react native project using the automation installation i.e, npx install-expo-modules@latest

But after installing it is giving the below error.

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
/Users/bhaveshkumar/Documents/AwesomeProject/android/app/src/main/java/com/awesomeproject/MainApplication.java:3: error: package expo.modules does not exist
import expo.modules.ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher;
                   ^
/Users/bhaveshkumar/Documents/AwesomeProject/android/app/src/main/java/com/awesomeproject/MainApplication.java:4: error: package expo.modules does not exist
import expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapper;
                   ^
/Users/bhaveshkumar/Documents/AwesomeProject/android/app/src/main/java/com/awesomeproject/MainActivity.java:2: error: package expo.modules does not exist
import expo.modules.ReactActivityDelegateWrapper;
                   ^
/Users/bhaveshkumar/Documents/AwesomeProject/android/app/src/main/java/com/awesomeproject/MainApplication.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
      new ReactNativeHostWrapper(this, new ReactNativeHost(this) {
          ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHostWrapper
  location: class MainApplication
/Users/bhaveshkumar/Documents/AwesomeProject/android/app/src/main/java/com/awesomeproject/MainApplication.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
      new ReactNativeHostWrapper(this, new MainApplicationReactNativeHost(this));
          ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHostWrapper
  location: class MainApplication
/Users/bhaveshkumar/Documents/AwesomeProject/android/app/src/main/java/com/awesomeproject/MainApplication.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onApplicationCreate(this);
    ^
  symbol:   variable ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher
  location: class MainApplication
/Users/bhaveshkumar/Documents/AwesomeProject/android/app/src/main/java/com/awesomeproject/MainApplication.java:99: error: cannot find symbol
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onConfigurationChanged(this, newConfig);
    ^
  symbol:   variable ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher
  location: class MainApplication
/Users/bhaveshkumar/Documents/AwesomeProject/android/app/src/main/java/com/awesomeproject/MainActivity.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    return new ReactActivityDelegateWrapper(this, new MainActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()));
```

Comment: Seeing similar problem with trying to install expo-av for remote url audio playback.

Application running on iOS but not seeing that expo-av is working correctly either after configuration but seeing expo-constants.

Comment: I have fixed this issue, it was issue with by react native version as it was expo module was not compatible with latest react native version.